# しかし、もしホロが何か動物が姿を変えたものだとしたら

Tags: grammar, particle-が

On page 43 of the first vol of the *Spice and Wolf* light novel, a part of a sentence reads

> しかし、もしホロが何か動物が姿を変えたものだとしたら

How do the two が particles function in the above sentence together with 変えた and 姿を?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> しかし、もしホロ**が**何か動物**が**姿を変えたものだとしたら...

You can parse it like this:

> しかし、もしホロが X だとしたら...
>   If we assume that Horo is X.

Where X is:

> 何か動物**が**姿を変えたもの
>   Some kind of animal that has changed form.